# PWA: Manifest is There, but Chrome Says "No Manifest Found"?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, progressive-web-apps

**UPDATE**

With no changes having been made, Lighthouse has mysteriously stopped showing the "No usable web app manifest found on page" message and is now showing "Timed out waiting for start_url to respond." That's a topic for another post of course.

I do not yet know why Lighthouse stopped showing the previous error message.

---

I've just added PWA features to my app for the first time. Chrome Lighthouse says "No usable web app manifest found on page."

[image]

But the Chrome Application>>Manifest tool reports that the manifest.json file is there -- and even reads in the data from it:

[image]

Here's what the manifest.json file looks like:

```
{
  "short_name": "mySiteName",
  "name": "mySiteName",
  "start_url": "/",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#ffffff",
  "theme-color": "#ffffff",
  "background_color": "#000000",
  "background-color": "#000000",
  "description": "my site description",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/images/app-images/myLogo.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "/images/app-images/myLogo.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ]
}
```

Why is Lighthouse saying the manifest.json isn't found -- when the Chrome Application>>Manifest tool says that it is?

**Update:**

A commenter asked if I'd linked the manifest in the `<head>`. Going to the production server and clicking `view source`, I see in the `<head>` tag:

```
<head>
    [.....]
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json" crossorigin="use-credentials">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

    <noscript>This site requires Javascript. Please activate JavaScript in your browser.</noscript>
    [.....]
</head>
```

If I paste `https://www.mywebsite.care/manifest.json` into the browser, my manifest.json file comes up. So it appears that I have linked the manifest.json file in the `<head>` section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that when you are updating a pwa implementation, it's not enough to delete the old serviceworker from the Chrome devtools Application tab -- it's also often necessary to delete the old Cache Storage on the Application tab as well.  I guess what was happening may have been a stale cache error.

Comment: Lighthouse continues to show my old manifest.json even though I have cleared data. Do you know how to delete it from the Application tab. Thanks.

Comment: @LewPerren, go to the Application tab, click "Service Workers" on the left, and click the "Unregister" link. Does that take care of it?

Comment: Thanks, I will try in the morning,

Answer (score 1):

It may happens because you might have not linked your manifest file in the html document head

Comment: Thanks for this comment, @Ayush. I believe I have linked the manifest file in the html document head. I've updated the post with additional info.

Comment: Wow, the simple things get you in the end...thanks for this

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I deleted the `sw.js` file and `workbox-e604aefe.js` in the public folder and then used the CLI `npm run build`.

It seems like if you don't delete those files manually then the build file does not let the manifest.json file reupdate those files and so your faulty `sw.js` file and `workbox-e604aefe.js` get served again and again.

Just delete those faulty old files and new updates will get created on the build automatically.